# PHP auto send email

Tags: php, email, send

The page doesn't load. I am trying to send an email from my PHP code. This is for auto-sending an email for a charity organization.

`

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$message = <<<EMAIL

$name

$message

EMAIL;

$header = 'hi';
if($_POST){
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)
$feedback = "Email Sent!";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<p id = "feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
<form action = "emailtest.php" method = "POST">
<label for = "name">Name: </label>
<input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name" /> <br />
<label for = "message"> Enter a Message: </label>
<textarea id = "message" name = "message" cols = "42" row = "9"></textarea> <br />
<input type = "submit" value = "Send Email">

</form>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: There's a missing semi-colon on the `mail()` call. Otherwise - check the webserver logs and see if there are errors in there.

Comment: @andrewsi the page now loads but the email is not sending

Comment: Yeah, because the string 'hi' does not constitute valid email headers. Look at the examples [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: @sammitch i took the header out but it still doesnt work

Comment: @user2908332 - the headers aren't required. You can remove it for now, and add it back in later if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

your first test is wrong, the `$_POST` variable will always be available, Also 'header' in the function does not correpond to the subject line or whatever you think it is but mail header(some info you only see when looking at the source including the id of the message, handling of the various mail servers etc...

Also please not that as is your code is vulnerable and your mailer could be used to spam others. http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/protect-script-from-email-injection.shtml
replace with something like

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$message = <<<EMAIL

$name

$message

EMAIL;

mail($to, $subject, $message)
$feedback = "Email Sent!";
}
```

Good luck !

Comment: the page loads now but no email is being sent

Answer (score -1):

The functionality of your code is arbitrary. 
The **mail()** function requires a preexisting SMTP mail server set up to be used. If you are running a WAMP stack or have not fully configured your stack, you may need to take extra step to set mail() up.

See for more info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that a missing SMTP server cause the pagen not to load?

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry I don't understand your question. I am commenting here on the failure of a specific function `mail()`. This function connects the PHP Apache server to a running SMTP service. The success of this function does not relate to the page loading but to the success of sending an email, which relies on an **email server**. If there is no SMTP server, it will not be possible to send an email.

Comment: If there is no mailserver (however that is configured), no mail is sent - that's right. But the OP has a problem with loading the page, not with sending a mail